# my state is still null although my firebase code is 100% correct(React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I made a react class component to handle questions retrieved from my firebase cloudstore, the firebase is 100% correct and was working fine before I implemented it in the class component

I am trying to fetch data and save them to state called "Questions", I am getting error that "Questions" is still null even after checking that the firebase code is completely correct

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import firebase from 'firebase';
const Config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  
  }
  
  
  firebase.initializeApp(Config);
 class Quiz extends Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      Questions: null,

      }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const questionsRef = db.collection('questions');
    questionsRef.get().then((snapshot)=>{
    
      const data=snapshot.docs.map((doc)=>({
        id:doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));
      console.log(data)
      this.setState({ Questions:data });
    });
  }
  render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-8">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header">
            Question
            <span className="float-right">
              Current Score
              <span className="badge badge-warning">

              </span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">
              {this.state.Questions.questions}
            </h5>
            <div>
              <ul>
                {this.state.Questions.questions.options.map(option => (
                  <li key={option.A}>
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      name="answer"
                      value={option.A}
                  
                      
                    />{" "}
                    {option.A}
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="row">&nbsp;</div>
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              
            >
              Submit Answer
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-4">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header">High Scores</div>
          <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li>
            <span>
                      </span>
                    </li>
               
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  );
}
}
 

export default Quiz;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore queries are asynchronous.  When you call get(), it will return immediately, and the callback from the returned promise will be invoked some time later, after the query completes.  There is no guarantee how long it will take.

Meanwhile, your component continues to render with the initial state of `{ Questions: null }`.  The fact that you initially have `null` in place during the first render is what the error message is trying to tell you.  The component will render again after `setState` is called, but you should add code to decide what you want to render when the initial null value is present, before the query is complete.  Many people use a spinner or other loading indicator.